# Has Permission function in discord v.13 (discord.js)

Tags: discord, discord.js

I tried to change my `Clear Command` so that it works on Discord v.13. My biggest Problem right now is the `hasPermission function`. I looked it up on the Discord.js/guide side and followed there instruction. Unfortunately I get this error when trying to change the old `hasPermission function`

My Intents:

```js
const intents = new Discord.Intents(513);

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents });
```

My Clear Command right now:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async message => {

    if(message.author.bot) return;
    let parts = message.content.split(" ");

  
  if(parts[0] == '.c')
    if(!message.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.MANAGE_ROLES)) return message.channel.send("You can't do that").then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 5000 }))
    if (!parts[1]) return message.channel.send('You forgot something here!').then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 3000 }))
    if (isNaN(parts[1])) return message.channel.send('Pls use a number!').then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 3000 }))
    if (parts[1] > 100) return message.channel.send('You can't delete more than 100 messages').then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 3000 }))
    if (parts[1] < 2) return message.channel.send('You can't delete less than 2 messages').then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 3000 }))
    message.channel.bulkDelete(parts[1])
    message.channel.send(`I deleted ${parts[1]} Messages!`).then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 3000 }))
```

My Error Code is:

```
if(!message.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.MANAGE_ROLES)) return message.channel.send("You can't do that").then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 5000 })) 
                              ^
```

^ ReferenceError: Permissions is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo there, it is

```js
message.member.permissions.has();
```

You are missing `s` at the end of the `permission`

Comment: That actually fixed my original error code but now i'm getting this one: 

 if(!message.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.MANAGE_ROLES)) return message.channel.send("You can't do that").then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 5000 }))
                                       ^

ReferenceError: Permissions is not defined

Comment: Change Permissions to Discord.Permissions and be sure you have `const Discord = require('discord.js')` on top